# Show distinct row in a group SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008, distinct

Here is the query that replicate the records

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    nameID int
);

insert into test
values(1,'test1',1),
      (1,'test2',2),
      (1,'test3',3),
      (1,'test4',4),
      (1,'test5',5)

select 
    t1.name,
    t2.name
from 
    (select * from test where nameID in (1,2)) t1 left join 
    (select * from test where nameID in (3,4,5)) t2 on t1 .id = t2.id
```

The current output is

test1   test3
test1   test4
test1   test5
test2   test3
test2   test4
test2   test5

But what I want to show in SSRS is

test1 test3
             test4
test2   test5

Basically on every `id` group I just want to show the distinct values.
(the logic behind is that a id group (one document) could have multiple approvor and soignee)
So far I tried to `HideDuplicates` and `group` with no luck.

Comment: I don't get logic for your desired output

Comment: Why second column needed? why `test2` and `test3` are within same row?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    nameID int
);

insert into test
values(1,'test1',1),
      (1,'test2',2),
      (1,'test3',3);

SELECT T2.Name, T1.Name
FROM Test T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM Test WHERE NameID IN (1, 3)) T2 
ON T1.NameID = T2.NameID;
```

Or

```
SELECT T1.Name, T2.Name
FROM Test T1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT * FROM Test WHERE NameID % 2 = 1) T2 
ON T1.NameID = T2.NameID;
```

Results:

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Name  |
+-------+-------+
| test1 | test1 |
| test2 |       |
| test3 | test3 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Sorry I did not explain well enough, I have edited the question.